# how to close TCP & UDP ports via osx command line

Tags: salt-stack

[WARNING ] Unable to bind socket, error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
The ports are not available to bind
// specially in Salt-master role?

Comment: First of all try to rephrase your problem in another way.SHow us what you tried and what exactly went wrong

Comment: sudo salt-master -l debug
Password:
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: parags-macbook-pro.local
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[INFO    ] Setting up the Salt Master
[WARNING ] Unable to bind socket, error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
The ports are not available to bind

Answer (score 0):

The salt-master is already running and is using the ports.

Stop the salt-master service and then run `sudo salt-master -l debug`

Comment: it finally adds upto same, rather the default port to be used is 4505/4506 , but it dosen't show any proccess allocated to this ports

Comment: sudo salt-master -l debug
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: parags-macbook-pro.local
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[INFO    ] Setting up the Salt Master
[WARNING ] Unable to bind socket, error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
The ports are not available to bind.. this happen mostly when in master conf file interface is other than localhost